Can we determine the positivity of this matrix?
Suppose $A$, $B$, and $P$ are three positive definite matrices where $A> B$, i.e., $A > B > 0$ and $P >0$.
Can we prove that $APA-BPB \geq 0$ ? Or is it even not true?
I try to find a counter-example, but I failed. My intuition tells me that it is probably true, but even for the most simple case where $P=I$ and $AA-BB \geq 0$ seems non-trivial to prove.

It is not true, even in the case where $P = I$. The converse to this does hold, however: if $A,B$ are positive semidefinite with $A^2 \geq B^2$, then $A \geq B$.

I know this specific point about $A^2 \geq B^2$ has been addressed on this site before, but here's a quick counterexample in the meantime:
$$
A = \pmatrix{4 & 2\2 & 4}, \quad B = \pmatrix{3&0\0&0}
$$

@BenGrossmann Thank you so much for your kind response! Indeed in this example B is semi-positive. We can modify it to: $$ A =\left(  \begin{array}{cc} 4 & 2 \ 2 & 5  \right{array} \right)  $$

@BenGrossmann Thank you so much for your kind response! Indeed in this example B is semi-positive. We can modify it to: A=[4 2; 2 5], and B = [3 0; 0 0.0001].
